# How to change a table constraint to deferrable in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have this simple contraint set on my sales table
    CONSTRAINT sales_stamping_id_key UNIQUE (company_id, stamping_id, invoice_number, billed)
and i can't seem to find a way to change this constraint to deferrable without deleting the constraint. Is there a way to do this???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can alter the unique constraint like so:

```
alter table foo add constraint bar_idx unique using index bar_idx deferrable;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html

Comment: Thanks I was using set constraint instead of add.